# Error Symfony Doctrine PostgreSQL : SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

Hi i'm using Symfony and i'm trying to connect my project to a PostgreSQL server version 9.6. I'have already edited the .env file. Then i did my migrations. So I have my new tables in the database, but when i'm creating an account in my web app i have this error.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.email AS email_4, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_5, t0.account_activated AS account_activated_6 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.email = ?' with params ["machin@bidule.fr"]:

SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.password...
```

I've already used

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But it changed nothing. I have also added the corrects extensions to the php.ini file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found an issue : "user" is keyword in postgreSQL. I renamed my entity and made migrations. Now it's working

Answer (score 7):

In future, instead of changing table name, add `@ORM\Table(name="`user`")`. as shown below. Note the the grave accent ( ` ) [diacritical mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="There is already an account with this username")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */

.....the rest of code continues...
```